# LeetCode Permutations - Stack overflow error

Tags: go, permutation, stack-overflow

https://leetcode.com/problems/permutations/discuss/18239/A-general-approach-to-backtracking-questions-in-Java-(Subsets-Permutations-Combination-Sum-Palindrome-Partioning)

According to the above post (Permutations), I want to overwrite it in Go with his algorithm.

But there is a stack overflow error occurs.

Below is my code. Can help me solve this problem, thx.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    nums := []int{1, 2, 3}
    ans := permute(nums)
    fmt.Println(ans)
}

func permute(nums []int) [][]int {
    result := make([][]int, 0)
    tempAry := make([]int, 0)
    backtrack(&result, tempAry, nums)
    return result
}

func backtrack(result *[][]int, temp []int, nums []int) {
    if len(nums) == len(temp) {
        *result = append(*result, temp)
    } else {
        for i := 0; i < len(nums); i++ {
            if binarySearch(nums[i], temp) != -1 {
                continue
            } else {
                temp = append(temp, nums[i])
                backtrack(result, temp, nums)
                temp2 := temp[0 : len(temp)-2]
                temp = temp2
            }
        }
    }
}

func binarySearch(target int, array []int) int {
    low := 0
    high := len(array) - 1
    for high > low {
        mid := (high + low) / 2
        if array[mid] > target {
            high = mid - 1

        } else if array[mid] < target {
            low = mid + 1
        } else {
            return mid
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

Comment: It'd be good if you 1) stated the problem very clearly - what is the algorithm this is trying to implement? and 2) explained how each function in your code is supposed to work - e.g. what its inputs mean, what its outputs are and what invariants are expected? For example if this is generating permutations of a slice I'm not sure why you need a binary search there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is an infinite recursion. That leads to stack overflows because the function return address and the function's arguments take stack space.

The problem comes from the loop: by the time the third level of recursion (the one that appends the 3) returns, it removed the 2 and the 3 from the slice. So the previous level, that should be finishing its second iteration, will see the 3 is missing, so it will call `backtrack` again, but that one will see the 3 is missing, but when it comes back the 2 and 3 are missing, so it will call `backtrack` recursively two more times, and so on and so on.

Comment: Yes, you're right. this explanation makes me know the recursion more better.